# Logout route issues in laravel web application

Tags: laravel, routes, logout

When I logged out from my laravel application and logged in again when I click on the logout button, the button is clickable but it is not going in the controller logout method. I have checked it by writing dd() and exit in the logout controller but they are not getting executed.

Every page is clickable and they are working properly except the logout route.

What should i do ??

Comment: So what does happen when you click the button?  Is your logout button a form, and if so does it use Javascript or is it a plain form?  Or is it a plain link?  What does your browser's devtools show?  Any errors on the console?  What network requests are happening?  How about your Laravel logs, anything there?  What about your web server logs, and PHP logs?  Maybe some CSS issues so the button is underneath another element?  You have a lot to investigate, start debugging! :-)

Answer (score 0):

For me this works:

```
<a href="{{ route('logout') }}"
   onclick="event.preventDefault();
     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
     {{ __('Logout') }}
</a>
<form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" class="d-none">
    @csrf
</form>
```